# Applescript Errors with Mail

Tags: error-handling, applescript

I made this quick Applescript application and it gave me an error, here is the coding:

```
set buyannounce to "AUTOMATIC SERVER EMAIL : BUY"
set transferannounce to "AUTOMATIC SERVER EMAIL : TRANSFER"
set signupannounce to "AUTOMATIC SERVER EMAIL : SIGNUP"
set sellannounce to "AUTOMATIC SERVER EMAIL : SELL"
set nowsignup to "0"
set announce to "AUTOMATIC SERVER EMAIL"


set ¬
    currentSignups ¬
        to the text returned ¬
    of (display dialog ¬
    ¬
        "How many current signups?" default answer "")


tell application "Mail"
set unreadMessages to (get every message of mailbox "INBOX" of account "Yahoo" whose read status is true)
repeat with eachMessage in unreadMessages

    if announce is in (get content of eachMessage) then

        if buyannounce is in (get content of eachMessage) then
            --buy email 
        end if
        if transferannounce is in (get content of eachMessage) then
            --transfer email
        end if
        if signupannounce is in (get content of eachMessage) then
            set nowsignup to nowsignup + 1
            set eachMessageTrimmed to ((characters 33 thru -1 of (get content of eachMessage)) as string)
            display dialog nowsignup
            set filepath to POSIX path of "/Users/obleopold/Dropbox/Accounts.csv"
            try
                set command to "open " & quoted form of filepath
                do shell script command
            end try
            delay 10
            repeat currentSignups times
                tell "System Events" to keystroke return
            end repeat
            repeat nowsignup times



                tell "System Events"
                    keystroke eachMessageTrimmed --here is where I am getting the error
                end tell

                tell "System Events" to keystroke return
                currentSignups = currentSignups + nowsignup
                set nowsignup to "0"

            end repeat
        end if




            if sellannounce is in (get content of eachMessage) then
        --sell email
            end if

        end if
    end repeat
end tell
end
end
end
end
```

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information. What was the error? What was it supposed to do?

Comment: Instead of `characters 33 thru...` try `text 33 thru...`, that should solve your error

Comment: The error I get when do it is: Can't make "" into type integer, and it highlights keystroke eachMessageTrimmed @Syon

Comment: Thank you, @Josh but when I did that it still gave me the error. Is it normal that it changed text to rich text when I compiled it?

Comment: Yes. Mail knows the "rich text" command so since your code is inside of a "tell app Mail" block of code it is using Mail's applescript dictionary. So the solution is to move your system events code outside the Mail block of code. You should not embed "tell" blocks of code within each other if you can avoid it. Your error is just one of the reasons to separate blocks of code.

Comment: @regulus6633, I am trying to avoid that now, can you please tell me the area I need to change it and an example of how to do so. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sure, see my post below.

Answer (score 1):

I did not check if your code works properly but here's one way to write your code to avoid the problems. You can use subroutines. When you call a subroutine from within a "tell" block of code you need to preface it with the word "my". This tells the script that the subroutine belongs to the script and not the application you are telling.

Notice that you can optimize your code by getting the message content once. Every time you "get content of eachMessage" there's a performance hit... so do it only once. Notice also that I added some delays between your keystroke commands. Normally you need these small delays to prevent errors when you are doing things like this. It gives your computer a little extra time to perform the keystrokes.

Good luck.

```
set buyannounce to "AUTOMATIC SERVER EMAIL : BUY"
set transferannounce to "AUTOMATIC SERVER EMAIL : TRANSFER"
set signupannounce to "AUTOMATIC SERVER EMAIL : SIGNUP"
set sellannounce to "AUTOMATIC SERVER EMAIL : SELL"
set nowsignup to "0"
set announce to "AUTOMATIC SERVER EMAIL"

set currentSignups to the text returned of (display dialog "How many current signups?" default answer "")

tell application "Mail"
    set unreadMessages to (get every message of mailbox "INBOX" of account "Yahoo" whose read status is true)

    repeat with eachMessage in unreadMessages
        set messageContent to content of eachMessage
        if announce is in messageContent then

            if buyannounce is in messageContent then
                --buy email 
            end if

            if transferannounce is in messageContent then
                --transfer email
            end if

            if signupannounce is in messageContent then
                set nowsignup to nowsignup + 1

                set eachMessageTrimmed to my trimMessageText(messageContent)
                display dialog nowsignup
                my openFilePath(POSIX path of "/Users/obleopold/Dropbox/Accounts.csv")
                delay 10
                repeat currentSignups times
                    my keystrokeSomething(return)
                    delay 0.2
                end repeat
                repeat nowsignup times
                    my keystrokeSomething(eachMessageTrimmed)
                    delay 0.2
                    my keystrokeSomething(return)
                    delay 0.2
                    currentSignups = currentSignups + nowsignup
                    set nowsignup to "0"
                end repeat
            end if

            if sellannounce is in messageContent then
                --sell email
            end if
        end if
    end repeat
end tell


(************* SUBROUTINES *****************)
on trimMessageText(messageText)
    try
        return text 33 thru -1 of messageText
    on error
        return messageText
    end try
end trimMessageText

on keystrokeSomething(something)
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke something
    end tell
end keystrokeSomething

on openFilePath(filepath)
    try
        do shell script "open " & quoted form of filepath
    end try
end openFilePath
```

The other way to separate your tell blocks would be something like this. But in your case it seems subroutines are easier.

```
tell application "Mail"
    -- do something
end tell

set eachMessageTrimmed to text 33 thru -1 of messageText

tell application "System Events"
    -- do something
end tell

do shell script "something"

tell application "Mail"
    -- do something
end tell
```

Comment: Huh, I've never heard them referred to as `subroutines`, does AS have something against calling them `methods` or `functions`?

Comment: Well actually in applescript they're called handlers... https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html

Comment: And here's what Wikipedia says about subroutines... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subroutine

Comment: Huh, I guess you learn something knew everyday. +1 for the thoroughness of the follow through :)

Answer (score 0):

System Events is an application, so for your tell blocks you need

```
tell application "System Events"
```

Instead of

```
tell "System Events"
```

Furthermore, to prevent nested tell blocks you can use:

```
tell application "System events"
    tell process "Mail"
        keystroke "My Keystroke"
    end tell
end tell
```

Or in one line:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Mail" to keystroke "My Keystroke"
```